# How to see js file of a website using web browser inspector tool?

Tags: javascript

Using web browser inspector tool, I was trying to see js source code of an website (https://www.cyberpunk.net/build/js/preorder-f96eab6808d90621a4a1.js) but all I can see is html code (view-source:https://www.cyberpunk.net/pl/pl/pre-order). I want to access js file from my browser, how to do that?

I am using lastest google chrome. Mentioned website is this one:https://www.cyberpunk.net/nl/en/pre-order

Comment: That HTML code contains several `<script>` tags, did you not look at those?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the network tab in Chrome dev tools and reload the page, you can see each individual item being loaded into the browser (images, scripts, etc.). If you use the 'JS' filter you should be able to narrow the files down to what you're looking for.

[image: network tab]